# How to run the squarring algorithm from opencarto on a shapefile with many polygons?

Tags: shapefile, java, opencarto

I want to square building surfaces which are almost rectangular. I didn't find any tool in an OSgis. But there is a java library opencarto which includes such an algorithm. I'm not a professional java developer, but as i can see in the code below there are two getter methods which wait for a polygon input. 
My Question is how can I select with a Filechooser in java the shapefile and make every single polygon of this shapefile running through this algorithm?
Or exists there almost a tool which can handle this?

```
public class Squarring {

public static Polygon get(Polygon poly) {
    return get(poly, 20, -1, 0.01);
}

public static Polygon get(Polygon poly, double angleToleranceDeg, int pointActivationLimitNb, double res) {
    Polygon poly2 = (Polygon) poly.clone();
    HashSet<GPoint> ps = new HashSet<GPoint>();
    HashSet<GSegment> segs = new HashSet<GSegment>();
    Decomposers.decomposeLimit(poly2, res, ps, segs, false, null);

    double o=new Orientation(poly2).getSidesOrientation();

    for (GSegment s : segs)..........
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  Please [edit] your question to include your code snippet as text pasted into the question rather than as an image.  Text is easier to read, can be copy/pasted by potential answerers to test, and is also makes it searchable for users with the same or similar problems.